# Which girl Parry was referring to after waking up?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, ending, the-fisher-king

In the end of *[The Fisher King](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiIv_6W6IHLAhXDbxQKHf8SAmgQFgg0MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FThe_Fisher_King&usg=AFQjCNFEUwx49lGy52YGBwudAqyIIMoFfA)*, when Parry was being woken up by Jack after a coma, he said he had had a dream and it was about a girl that he really missed.

Who is he referring to? His current girlfriend or his ex girlfriend that got killed by that desperate, insane guy who kills people with a shotgun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think **he was talking about his dead wife**: Parry is saying he remembers everything about what happened and forgives Jack, so Jack can find peace, that's why he was crying (Jack is the wounded, tormented Fisher King and Parry the simple-minded man that helps him, in my interpretation of the movie).

Answer (score 0):

Speaking while going in flow with the film, one might conclude that Parry was talking about his new girlfriend since he was extremely infatuated with her before he got into an accident and his feelings, in ways, "resumed" when he woke up.

While interpreting the film from a different perspective, I choose to agree with mattiav27's answer above. His interpretation is very interesting.